# frontend form action: save as draft or publish

Tags: templating, form, entry, frontend, entry-form

in my frontend entry form I have a "save as draft" submit button.
The current action for this form is the following, which saves the entry submitted through the form as a draft (status: disabled):

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entryRevisions/saveDraft">
```

Next to the "save as draft" button I would like to have a "publish" button. If the user clicks on it the entry should be submitted as "status: live". If the user clicks on "save as draft" it should be submitted as "status: disabled". Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `entryRevisions/publishDraft`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entryRevisions/publishDraft">
```

You can see the specific inputs it is looking for here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/controllers/EntryRevisionsController.php#L188

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your support. As I have two buttons in the form "save as draft" and "publish" I want the user to click either or. So either the forms content is being saved as draft or it is being published.

Comment: Maybe something similar than this: `<input type="submit" action="entryRevisions/saveDraft" value="Save as draft">
    <input type="submit" action="entryRevisions/entries/saveEntry" value="Publish">`. Unfortunately this is not working. Any idea how to make it work?